# Py2exe - module does not find

Tags: python, py2exe

I'm trying to make an exe file from my (2) py files. In one file is bs4 imported - `import bs4`
When I try to execute this script:

```
setup(
    console = ['gui.py'],
    options = {
        'py2exe': {
            'packages': ["bs4"]
        }
    }
)
```

the console returns:

```
    C:\Users\uživatel\PycharmProjects\mail_checker>setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
*** searching for required modules ***
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u×ivatel\PycharmProjects\mail_checker\setup.py", line 12, in <m
odule>
    'packages': ["bs4"]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 243, in run
    self._run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 296, in _run
    self.find_needed_modules(mf, required_files, required_modules)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\build_exe.py", line 1306, in find_n
eeded_modules
    mf.import_hook(f)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 719, in import_hook
    return Base.import_hook(self,name,caller,fromlist,level)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 136, in import_hook
    q, tail = self.find_head_package(parent, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\mf.py", line 204, in find_head_pack
age
    raise ImportError, "No module named " + qname
ImportError: No module named bs4
```

So I suppose that I haven't setup.py written correct. Could you give me an advice? Thanks

Comment: Any difference if you are explicit about which python you are using, as in `python setup.py py2exe`?  `setup` might be using a version that doesn't have `bs4` available.

Comment: try `'includes': ["bs4"]` instead of `'packages': ["bs4"]`

Comment: @joaquin I tried but no effect.

Comment: @ScottHunter I tried C:\Python27\python.exe setup.py py2exe but no change.

Comment: Actually you do not need to 'include' bs4 in setup.py. Py2exe read the imports and search for them. 'includes' options are only needed in some problematic cases.

Comment: @joaquin I run setup.py without include or packages before, It made an exe file, but It didn't run so I run it in cmd and it returned something about bs4, not find or something like that.

Comment: can you `import bs4` on a python shell (do you have bs4 in your installation and is it accesible) ?

Comment: @joaquin Yes I can: 'C:\Users\uživatel\PycharmProjects\mail_checker>C:\Python27\python.exe
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:08:48) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bs4
>>>'

Comment: Do you also have the `chardet` package?  I'm unable to reproduce your results, but immediately after including the bs4 module py2exe gathered up the chardet module as well - perhaps it's incorrectly reporting the actual module it can't completely load.

Comment: @joaquin I have bs4 installed as egg file, so I tried to open this egg, and put bs4 folder into site-packages, maybe it helped, I can execute setup.py now. But when I try to open gui.exe, nothing happens... but thats probably another problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

The problem was probably that I have installed bs4 (and xlsxwriter) by easy_install which creates *.egg files in `site-packages` folder. Py2exe couldn't find bs4 in `site-packages` for some reason. So I tried to open BeautifulSoup egg file and copy bs4 folder into `site-packages` folder, I did the same with xlsxwriter.

*It helped. Program works properly.*